# jqueryui datepicker to allow age from 18-50

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to allow customer within age 18-50 in my application and I am using jqueryui datepicker.
I am not getting a way for events to be employed for this!

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While investigating, I got a way to do this.

```
jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: '-18y',
    minDate: '-68y',
});
```

where #datepicker is my selector.

If there's a better way to do the same, then comments are most welcome!

Comment: Better way  than this ? Actually what do u mean ?

Comment: @Nithin since I am learning new ways, many other around the world may have other ways to do the same! Its good to learn different ways to do the same thing. I hope you agree

Answer (score 0):

try this .. its another way...

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;



$('input').datepicker({
    minDate: 'today-18250',
    maxDate: 'today-6570',
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
         var str = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
         var minDateArr = $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate" ).split('/')

        var minDate = new Date(minDateArr[2],minDateArr[0]-1,minDateArr[1]);
        if ($.inArray(str) != -1){
            return  [false, 'special']
        }
        else if(date < minDate ){
             return [false, 'not-special']
        }
        else{
            return [true,"special"];
        }
    }
});
```